# How to merge two models into one single form?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Is it possible to merge two different models into a single form? if yes then please provide me with the solution.
basically, I want to create a form in which I can also add images but it is not working as I want to make it work.

models.py:

```
 class Mobile(models.Model):
      brand = models.CharField(max_length=30)
      price = models.IntegerField(default=1)
      color = models.CharField(max_length=30)
      screen_size = models.IntegerField(default=5)
      os = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='Samsung')

      def __unicode__(self):
          return self.brand


class MobileImage(models.Model):
     device = models.ForeignKey(Mobile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/images/')

     def __unicode__(self):
         return self.device
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Mobile, Laptop, MobileImage


class AddMobileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Mobile
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py:

```
def addmobile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        mobileform = AddMobileForm(request.POST)
        if mobileform.is_valid():

           mobileform.save()
           return redirect('mobile')
    else:
        mobileform = AddMobileForm()

  context = {
    'mobile_form': mobileform
}
return render(request, 'device/mobile_form.html', context)
```

Comment: You can have two forms . One for Mobile and second for MobileDevice and then in views.py you can use both of them

Comment: yeah I know it but this is not a professional way to add things through forms

Comment: Why is not profesional? You want to write more code to do what you want instead using two forms?

Comment: okay got your point.

Comment: let you inform ina while

Comment: not working bro

Comment: Do you have any specific number of images that user can upload ? Simple solution is for example if you want front and back image of mobile then you can define two ```ImageField``` in the same ```Mobile``` model.

Comment: Can you show us how you did it?

Comment: bro it is already given above